# How to draw circles inside each other with different widths?

Tags: java

Im trying to draw circles inside of each other which have the same centres. 
But the width should be different for each circle - it should be done inside a while loop.

The result should look like the picture i have uploaded:
 [image: circles]

My code is shown below:

```
package modelwhile;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class exercise4_figure3 extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    GridPane root = initContent();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("Loops");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private GridPane initContent() {
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(200, 200);
    pane.add(canvas, 0, 0);
    drawShapes(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D());
    return pane;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

// circle figure begins here
private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {

    int x = 80;
    int y = 80;
    int r1 = 20;
    int r2 = 60;

    while (r1 <= 80) {
        gc.strokeOval(x - r2, y - r2, r1, r2);
        r1 = r1 + 10;

    }
}
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't moving on the x-axis to account for the added width of each new oval. You need to move half the distance being added to the oval in order to keep them all in the same relative position.

Below is your `drawShapes()` method updated to include this movement. You'll notice I removed your `x`, `y`, and `r2` variables because they didn't really have any need to be variables since nothing was done with them.

```
private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
    int r = 20;
    while (r <= 80) {
        gc.strokeOval(80-(r/2), 80, r, 60);
        r = r + 10;
    }
}
```